# Performance Impact of the Global Assembly Cache

Tags: .net, dll, gac, infrastructure

Apologies for the long-winded nature of this question. **TL;DR: jump to the last paragraph**.

Been scratching my head about this for a while now and cannot think of a way to test my theory that **multiple copies of the same DLL introduce a performance overhead**. One of our servers have 20-30 pieces of in-house analysis software that references a monolithic kernel that handles *Business Logic and Data-Access* to our central database. The **/bin** directory for each application has a local copy of this ~5MB DLL stored within it, which presumably* gets loaded into memory when each application is first run. Probably not a big deal now, but when we get to 100+ (planned) agents running in this manner I start to hear alarm bells.

I've read several articles online (e.g: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4352/Demystifying-the-NET-Global-Assembly-Cache) which talk about the security/integrity benefits of deploying common libraries in the **.NET GAC**, but nothing touches on the subject of performance, the only sure-fire topic that will get upper management's interest.

What I want to know is, when a Global Assembly is referenced in a project, does it share the same library instance as other consumer applications, or does an application simply load everything it needs into its own, separate area at runtime?

Comment: The only possible benefit is that the same loaded assembly can be used and thus reduce some memory. I know the base class libraries do this in .NET 4, but not sure exactly how one sets that up.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to ascertain! If two apps load the same version of an assembly in parallel, that feels inefficient. What I don't know is whether the GAC solves this specific problem...

Comment: From what I can see in Process Explorer, the assembly needs a `DomainNeutral` flags.

Comment: This looks promising... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/08/05/208375.aspx

Comment: According to that, ASP.NET already sets `MultiDomainHost`, so GAC'd assemblies should be loaded in the shared domain. Try it with Process Explorer.